# Django Admin - Add using intermediary form

Tags: django-forms, django-admin, django-views, url-routing

I had posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153599/django-refresh-modelform-in-admin-with-instance-derived-data) without any result. I fear it may be how I posed it...

In the admin, I would like the Add button to direct the user to a different view than the normal form (that would simply consist of a search field and button). After the 'search' form has been validated, it would then send the user to the standard add/change form with some instance data. What is the best method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I got the Tumbleweeds bronze star for dearth of responses to this question. I ended up partially solving it as follows...

Added a get_urls method to my model's admin

```
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_urls()
    addl = patterns(',
        (r'^add/$', 'MyApp.views.my_add_view)
    )

return addl + urls
```

Created a form for the 'Add' view

```
from django import forms
from MyApp.models import MyModel

class LookupForm(forms.Form):
    pk = ''
    url = forms.URLField(max_length=_URLMAXLEN, label='Video URL', 
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'60', 'autofocus':'autofocus'}))

    def clean_url(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data['url']

        #    some validation of 'value' here
        #    ...

        self.pk = somefoo(value)
        return value
```

And in views, I redirect to the change form after validating and saving the model instance

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from MyApp.forms import LookupForm

def my_add_view(request):
    confirm = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LookupForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            if 'confirm_button' in request.POST:
                foo_save()  #   save model instance

                #   LookupForm's 'pk' property set during some clean_ method
                href = reverse('admin:MyApp_MyModel_change', args=(form.pk,))
                return HttpResponseRedirect(href)

            elif 'search_button' in request.POST:
                confirm = foo_context() #   some context from the search results

    else:
        form = LookupForm()

    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'form': form, 'confirm': confirm})
```

Unfortunately I cannot achieve my goal of displaying the change form with instance data. Instead of having to save and redirect to the change_form, I would prefer to be able to direct with `MyModelForm(instance=some_instance)`